# Adding the same number multiple times to an empty array in C

Tags: c, function, sorting

This is a piece of code to add the same number multiple times to an empty array but when I am printing the now non empty array, I am getting some other values:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void sort_0(int arr[100], int i, int n){
    int final_array[100], c=0;

    // Count the number of '0' in the array
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i] == 0){
            c++;
        }
    }

    // Add the c number of '0' to the final_array
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        scanf("%d",final_array[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        printf("%d ", final_array[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    int arr[100], i, n;

    // Entering the size of the array
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Entering n elements into the array
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    sort_0(arr,i,n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the number of times `0` appears in the array is counted. Then the count is taken as the range and `0` is adding to the empty array `final_array` count times.

If `c = 5`, the `final_array = {0,0,0,0,0}`

Expected Output:

```
arr = {0,1,4,3,0}
Output = 2
```

I am not getting any output

Comment: scanf("%d", &arr[i])

Comment: Please also show the expected output vs. the actual output (which of these is {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}?) and the code used to print the array contents and how sort_0 is called.

Comment: Unrelated, it looks like i should not be function parameter, but a local variable in the function.

Comment: I have already written this part but forgot to add it here. It is still not working.

Comment: Basically, you want to create an array that has a number of `0` equal to `c`? Am i right?

Comment: can you  add the output you are getting please add more details to the question.

Comment: I added the whole code and the expected output. I hope this helps you. I am not able to add "0" to the new array

Comment: @PraneethRavuri What is the input that you give?

Comment: 6
0 1 2 3 0 0 
The first input is for the size of the array
The second line contains the elements to be entered into the first array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know how much `0` you'll need to add to your `array_final` I figured out that a better solution could be to create that array after you have the number of `0` of the first array. Also, I see no reason why you were passsing `i` to the function since you can simply define it in the function itself.

```
void sort_0(int arr[10], int n, int* c){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i] == 0){
                (*c)+= 1;
            }
        }
}


int main (void) {
    int size;
    
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    
    int c = 0;
    sort_0(arr, size, &c);
    
    printf("C is: %d\n",c);
    int* final_array;
    if ((final_array=malloc(c * sizeof(int)))==NULL) // should always check malloc errors
    { 
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<c;i++) {
        final_array[i]= 0;
    }
    
    printf("{");
    for (int i=0;i<c-1;i++) {
        printf("%d,", final_array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d}\n",final_array[c-1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my query. I still need to learn more about malloc.

Comment: `malloc` allows you to allocate memory dinamically. The part `malloc(c*sizeof(int))` means you're creating an array of size `c` which contains elements type `int`. It's the equivalent of `int array[c]` if you want to change the whole `malloc` part.

Comment: @MatteoPinna There was a small bug in your code, I fixed, just check if the code is fine

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Just had to remove a `{` too many.